# TableView won't populate

Tags: swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I've added a UITableView control to a UIAlertController to create a custom list picker. Everything worked fine until I tried to move all of my code into a new ListPicker class. Originally I had this code in the main viewcontroller and called `self.present` at the end of the `showListPicker` method. Everything worked fine then and my list populated properly with my items. But after moving to a separate class, I needed to reference the calling ViewController in my method call so I could present the alert over the calling ViewController. After doing this, everything works except my table view will not show any rows. The `numberOfRowsInSection` returns the correct number of rows but the `cellForRowAt` is never invoked.

I've read some other posts that mentioned constraints being an issue. Something like the constraints were preventing the rows from being visible and therefore never having their data methods invoked. They were using interface builder though and the solution was to accept the constraint fixes.

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

I appreciate the help.

Thanks,
Joel

[Empty TableView Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqBy5.png)

```
class ListPicker: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   
//MARK: Variables

    var items: [String]?
  
//MARK: ViewController Events

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

//MARK: TableView Events

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        
        cell.textLabel!.text = items![indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

//MARK: Support Methods

    func showListPicker(
        viewController: UIViewController,
        title: String? = "Select Item",
        message: String? = nil,
        items: [String]?,
        itemSelected: (@escaping (_ item: String) -> ())
    ) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: title,
            message: "\(message ?? "")\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
            preferredStyle: .alert
        )
        
        let rect = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 250,
            height: 250
        )

        let tableView = UITableView(frame: rect, style: .plain)
            tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
        
            tableView.rowHeight = 35
            tableView.backgroundColor = .white
            tableView.separatorInset.right = 15
            tableView.bounces = false
            tableView.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
         
        alert.view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.subviews[0].topAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.subviews[0].bottomAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.subviews[0].leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alert.view.subviews[0].rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("OK")})
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("cancel")})

        alert.addAction(okAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        viewController.present(alert, animated: true) {
            if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
                itemSelected(items![row])
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) say: "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

Comment: I think I remember seeing that in some other threads as well. So I should probably just create a custom list picker control. I want it to look and feel like the alert control so I figured it was easiest to just add the tableview to the alert itself. I'm still curious to know why it no longer works when I subclass it. I must be missing something. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The reason it's not working could be completely internal to the implementation of UIAlertController and nothing you're doing wrong.  Or it could be that you could make it work, at least until a new iOS breaks it, but you should go custom in this case. That's also better UX, alert controllers are supposed to have a standard appearance

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to create a custom control like you suggested. You know if there is Apple documentation showing the design specs for a UIAlert? I.e. Font, Font size, etc? I'm sure I can just eyeball it. I user a lot of other UIAlerts in my app and want to make sure this listbox control looks identical. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No, and you can't eyeball because the font used and the appearance is dynamic - based on user settings like accessibility, preferred font sizes, bold text preference etc.